# Heat equation: Energy $\int_{\Omega}u(t, x) dx$ is decreasing with positive initial data and $u=0$ on the boundary

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation, maximum-principle

From *David Borthwick - Introduction to Partial Differential Equations, Exercise 6.3b* (paraphrased),

> Let $\Omega \subset \Bbb R^n$ be a bounded domain with piecewise $C^1$ boundary. Suppose $u(t,x)$ satisfies the heat equation $$u_t - \Delta u = 0, \\ u(0,x) > 0 \quad\text{for } x\in \Omega, \\ u(t,x) = 0 \quad\text{for } x\in \partial\Omega.$$ Define the total thermal energy at time $t$ by $$U(t) = \int_{\Omega}u(t,x)\,\Bbb dx.$$ Show that $U(t)$ is decreasing.

My attempts so far:

1. Using the divergence theorem, I can start like
   $$U'(t) = \int_{\Omega} u_t(t, x) \,\Bbb dx = \int_{\Omega} \Delta u(t, x) \,\Bbb dx = \int_{\partial\Omega} \nabla u(t, x) \cdot \mathbf{n} \,\Bbb dx = \ldots ?$$
2. By the maximum principle, it should end like
   $$\ldots = \int_{?} -u(t,x) \,(?)\,\Bbb dx \leq \int_{?} -\min_{[0,t]\times \bar{\Omega}} u(t,x) \,(?)\,\Bbb dx \leq 0$$
   since $u(t,x)\geq 0$ for $(t,x) \in (\{0\}\times\Omega) \cup ([0,t]\times \partial \Omega)$.
3. For the missing steps in the middle, I get stuck because I can no longer “integrate by parts” to bring $\nabla u$ “up” to $u$. Also, the negative sign seems to be crucial to prove $U$ is decreasing, but I have no idea where it could come from.
4. Alternatively observe that $u_t$ also satisfies a heat equation. Maybe we can use the maximum principle on $u_t$ directly, but we don’t know $u_t(0,x)$ for $x\in \Omega$.

Are there more things to observe or are these the right tracks? Preferably only elementary results related to heat equation would be used. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the Hopf's lemma? (link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopf_lemma)

Comment: Thank you! The lemma seems powerful. Since we haven't learnt about harmonic functions / Laplace equation yet (I see the proof of the lemma needs Harnack's inequality which in turn needs Poisoon's formula), I wonder if there is a proof to the question not relying on such? Sorry that I cannot accept the answer although I appreciate it. I have edited the question to make it more specific.

Comment: no worries. I appreciate your feedback